# How do you enable gzip compression for favicon.ico?

Tags: gzip, apache, favicon

How do you enable Apache to compress favicon?

```
FAILED - (11.6 KB, compressed = 5.7 KB - savings of 5.9 KB) - http://website/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 13):

Judging from your example, the fail is from the WebPagetest.
Add the line below to the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf` (for Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
```

Reload apache afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't work with 2.4 on Fedora 25. `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` does though.

Comment: "66,82 % of favicons [in a 4 million sample] use the media type image/x-icon with image/vnd.microsoft.icon making up the rest." https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/favicon-compression.html

Answer (score 9):

Here is my configuration for assets compression with Nginx :

```
gzip on;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers  4 32k;
gzip_types  text/plain
            application/x-javascript
            text/xml
            text/css
            font/woff
            application/font-woff
            font/truetype
            font/opentype
            font/eot
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
            image/svg+xml
            image/x-icon;
gzip_vary on;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use imagemagick to compress the ico file:

```
compress -color 16 PATHTOORIGINAL/file.ico PATHTONEW/file.ico
```